# GUI based Forms creation and data management

Tags: open-source, java

I am looking for an open source project or solution (preferably Java based) which basically allows me to create forms & persist the data into a back end data store (SQL, NO-SQL doesn't matter but preferable if it is customizable). The GUI should allow me to define table structure, create forms using GUI and map them to columns, relationship management etc and the UI should be customizable.

- Basically, I have a friend who requires an application which is 95%
  form based and with basic form fields.
- They have 1 java backend developer and 1 UI designer who can do UI customization.
- I should basically be able to define the data model, relationships,
  business  logic etc using a GUI and generate the forms as needed.
- Role-based access is necessary (i.e. users may be admin, approver,
  submitter etc for eg.)
- Forms should be accessible based on roles and some business logic may
  change based on roles as well.

Is there anything that you guys know of which could satisfy my requirement? Happy to clarify any questions.

Comment: [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) might meet your needs. But it will not entirely create your forms automatically. I have found that expectation to be unrealistic but for the simplest of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Pimcore (an open source digital experience platform) with its data objects would fit your requirements very well. It is PHP / Symfony though.

Comment: OP, did you look at this? Any comments?